# Создать класс агрегатор используя делегаты

Tags: c#, делегаты

нужна помощь в лабораторной работе. Я студент заочной формы обучения. Задание:

> Создать класс агрегатор со следующими возможностями:
>
> 1. Посчитать сумму любого количества чисел
> 2. Посчитать произведение любого количества чисел
> 3. Найти максимальное среди любого количества чисел

Не могу понять как именно посчитать сумму(произведение) ЛЮБОГО КОЛИЧЕСТВА чисел при помощи делегатов.
Буду благодарен любой помощи.

Comment: Любого количества это значит вам нужно использовать `List<int>` или `int[]` и циклы для подсчета суммы и произведения и нахождения максимального числа.

Comment: Я понимаю, что в данной ситуации нужно использовать List<int>(даже лучше его, чтобы не увеличивать каждый раз размер массива, количество чисел введенное будет разным), но я не совсем понимаю, как сюда прикрутить делегаты.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы тоже хотел посмотреть, как в этом случае могут использоваться делегаты. Нет сомнений только в том, что если речь идет о любом количестве параметров, используем *params*. Самому пришло в голову только такое:

```
int GetResult(Func<int[], int> func, params int[] numbers)
{
    return func(numbers);
}
```

И такая функция для передачи в метод, например:

```
int Sum(params int[] numbers)
{
    return numbers.Sum(); // Linq
}
```

Comment: тип `Func<int[], int>` - Это делегат

Answer (score 0):

А меня скорее смутило `Создать класс агрегатор...`, вероятно что-то такое должно быть

```
class NumericalOperations
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Func<List<int>, int>> _operations;

    public NumericalOperations(Dictionary<string, Func<List<int>, int>> operations)
    {
        _operations = operations;
    }

    public Dictionary<string, int> GetOperationResults(params int[] numbers)
    {
        return GetOperationResults(numbers.ToList());
    }

    public Dictionary<string, int> GetOperationResults(List<int> numbers)
    {
        var result = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach (var item in _operations)
        {
            result.Add(item.Key, item.Value.Invoke(numbers));
        }

        return result;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ops = new Dictionary<string, Func<List<int>, int>>
        {
            ["Сумма"] = ns => ns.Sum(),
            ["Произведение"] = ns => ns.Aggregate((n1, n2) => n1 * n2),
            ["Максимальное"] = ns => ns.Max()
        };

        var numsOps = new NumericalOperations(ops);

        var nums = new List<int> { 5, 10, 54, 12, 23};
        var results = numsOps.GetOperationResults(nums);

        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{result.Key} = {result.Value}");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

Да, и при вычислении произведения очень быстро возникает переполнение, так что вероятно надо бы использовать вместо `int`, например `decimal`.

Comment: скорее всего достаточно было одну операцию в конструктор передать и коллекцию чисел в метод, либо наоборот :)

Comment: @Grundy это, пожалуй, пусть автор вопроса правит как ему заблагорассудится. Я лишь дал общую идею решения.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs

```
public static int Sum(this IEnumerable<int> source) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    int sum = 0;
    checked {
        foreach (int v in source) sum += v;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Если надо параметрами, используй `params`.